# Column text being cut off in report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I made a Crystal Report with values from my table. All the columns display correctly, except for one which cuts off early. It should say "Test 10" but the "10" part is missing. I connect to the database but overrule the connection in my code.

Is the "10" part not displaying because of my override? Or is something else causing this?

```
Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument()
cryRpt.Load("Location\report.rpt")

Dim cryRpttableLogoninfos As New TableLogOnInfos()
Dim cryRpttableLogoninfo As New TableLogOnInfo()
Dim cryRptConnectionInfo As New ConnectionInfo()
Dim cryRptTables As Tables

'para1
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue
crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = value
crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("@parameter")
crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
crParameterValues.Clear()
crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

'para2
Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions1 As ParameterFieldDefinitions
Dim crParameterFieldDefinition1 As ParameterFieldDefinition
Dim crParameterValues1 As New ParameterValues
Dim crParameterDiscreteValue1 As New ParameterDiscreteValue
crParameterDiscreteValue1.Value = value
crParameterFieldDefinitions1 = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
crParameterFieldDefinition1 = crParameterFieldDefinitions1.Item("@parameter1")
crParameterValues1 = crParameterFieldDefinition1.CurrentValues
crParameterValues1.Clear()
crParameterValues1.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue1)
crParameterFieldDefinition1.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues1)

cryRptConnectionInfo.ServerName = servername
cryRptConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = databasename
cryRptConnectionInfo.UserID = userid
cryRptConnectionInfo.Password = password
cryRptConnectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = False

cryRptTables = cryRpt.Database.Tables
For Each CrTable As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table In cryRptTables
cryRpttableLogoninfo = CrTable.LogOnInfo
cryRpttableLogoninfo.ConnectionInfo = cryRptConnectionInfo
CrTable.ApplyLogOnInfo(cryRpttableLogoninfo)
Next

cryRpt.RecordSelectionFormula = "{table.value} = " & value
```

Comment: I changed the database connection on the report and disabled the code in vb.net that overruled the connection but its still hapening ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In report viewer,

i>select the label where ur 'Test 10' data is shown..

ii>write click on that lable and select Field Format option..

iii>In first tab check 'Can Grow' option .

Comment: Tanx m8 you where wright its working but its Always comming on the second line of the object you know how i can keep it on the first line there is plenty of room.

Comment: I increased the label to with of entire page but its still putting the numbers on second rule any idee

Comment: I solved it there whas a vbLf code between the name and the numbers i cuddent see it in sql server but when i debugd and clicked the field i saw it